# How to get the information of semaphore with pthread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have written a program using pthread.h and semaphore.h

And I found that there are only few functions in semaphore.h as followed:

```
int  sem_close(sem_t *);
int  sem_destroy(sem_t *);
int  sem_getvalue(sem_t * __restrict, int * __restrict);
int  sem_init(sem_t *, int, unsigned int);
sem_t*sem_open(const char *, int, ...);
int  sem_post(sem_t *);
int  sem_timedwait(sem_t * __restrict, const struct timespec * __restrict);
int  sem_trywait(sem_t *);
int  sem_unlink(const char *);
int  sem_wait(sem_t *);
```

I want to know, which thread will get the semaphore and how many semaphores will the thread get? How to do it? Can I do that?

PS: Here "get" means that, the thread calls the function "sem_wait" which reduce the value of semaphore

If I can't get the information of semaphore, is there any mechanism to make sure that one thread can get only one semaphore?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does it mean for a thread to "get" a semaphore?

Comment: In the thread, it call sem_wait and decrease the value of semaphore@ScottHunter

Comment: The only operations mandated on a semaphore are P/V, post and wait.

Comment: I know. here "get" means the thread call the function sem_wait@MartinJames

Comment: SysV semaphores (not the posix semaphores you are using) allow you to query what process last performed an operation on the semaphore so if the last operation happened to a wait you could get that information.  The question should be why require it.  If it is for debugging a simple log can tell you the same thing.

Comment: _is there mechanism to make sure that one thread can get only one semaphore?_ Can you explain _why_ you want to do that? Perhaps there's a better way for doing what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

sem_getvalue will tell you the value of the semaphore; knowing its initial value means you can determine how many processes "got" the semaphore.  However, the value you get may be stale by the time you get it.

Since the thread did all of the "getting" and releasing, it can determine how many it "got" for itself, and, if necessary, make that information available to other threads.

As for insuring each thread only "gets" one semaphore, I think you'll have to write your code to not REQUEST another semaphore if it already "has" one.

Comment: yeah  how to do that?(not REQUEST another semaphore if it already "has" one.)

Comment: If your code isn't stuck waiting for wait to return, it has that semaphore until it releases it, which is all under your control.  So until you release it, don't request another one.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, simply use the `pthread_self()` function on the thread that obtained the semaphore to get its ID.  If you need other threads knowing the ownership information of a semaphore, you could setup a simple data-structure like an array or hash table, etc. to keep track of which thread is holding which semaphore.  In order to avoid issues with updating the table, make sure that only the thread that holds the semaphore is able to write to the ownership table for the semaphore that is being held, and all the other threads that don't hold the semaphore are only allowed to read from the table.

Comment: keep track of the thread and semaphore, it means to use the Condtion Variable？